# Converting a Bundle that contains bundles to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, bundle

I have a bundle that I would like to convert to one big JSONObject so that I can send it through a web service later on.  This main bundle contains mainly strings and integers, but it also contains another bundle, which in that contains bundles that have sets of 4 key value pairs.

Here is a diagram to clear up any confusion:
[image]

Code:

```
private JSONObject convertBundleToJSON(Bundle b)
{
    //the main json object to be returned
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


    Set<String> keys = b.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        try {
            // json.put(key, bundle.get(key)); see edit below
            json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(b.get(key)));
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            //Handle exception here
            Log.d("Convert Bund", e.toString());
        }
    }


    JSONObject fvl = new JSONObject();


    int i = 0;

    //error right here - b is a bundle of bundles; trying to iterate through
    Set<Bundle> bundles = (Set<Bundle>) b.get("field_value_list");
    for (Bundle bun : bundles)
    {

        JSONObject f = new JSONObject();
        try {

            f.put("fld_value_decode", bun.get("fld_value_decode"));
            f.put("fld_id", bun.get("fld_id"));
            f.put("fld_value", bun.get("fld_value"));
            f.put("fld_name", bun.get("fld_name"));

            fvl.put(i+"",f);

            i++;

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            //Handle exception here
            Log.d("FVL Convert Bund", e.toString());
        }
    }


    try {
        json.put("field_value_list", fvl);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return json;
}
```

But I get a casting exception at the error line.  It doesn't like the cast between bundle and set.  Any ideas or alternative ways to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this sophisticated way, you can simply achieve this by creating a model class which is parcelable.

Simply add those json to that model and further passing it, using it would be simpler.